# JSON to MVC Api Controller via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

So I'm trying to add a "like" function to some blog posts by POSTing some JSON through ajax to the MVC api controller.

Models:

```
public class Blog{
  public int ID{get;set;}
  public string Title{get;set;}
  //Some more stuff
  public virtual ICollection<Likes> Likes {get;set;}
}    

public class Likes{
  public int ID{get;set;}
  public string UserName{get;set;}
  //Some more stuff
  public virtual Blog Blog{get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public void Post(Likes like){
  if(ModelState.IsValid){
    db.Likes.Add(like)
    db.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

The below `return` is passed into the `JSON.stringify()` in the ajax call:

```
var UserName = "Dave";
//More stuff
var Blog = "????";

return {UserName:UserName, More Stuff, Blog:Blog}
```

So that last line is my problem I think, what do I pass in for "Blog"? I have tried using the ID of the Blog but it's still null in the controller. It seems the controller wants a full Blog model instead of just the ID, is there a way around this or am I doing something bad?

TLDR I guess is: What to pass to a field that's a `public virtual Blog Blog{get;set;}` in the model when sending JSON to the controller?

P.S. My code works when I don't include the "Blog" as part of the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are posting a `like` then this would probably do the thing

```
{
 ID : 789 //ID of the Like
 UserName : "Username",
 Blog : {
   ID : 789 //id of the blog
  }
}
```

This way you will have the id of the blog and would be mapped correctly.

But i would advise you make a separate view model of the following structure

```
public LikeAjax
{
 public string UserName{get; set;}
 public int BlogId {get; set;}
}
```

then send json like below

```
{
 UserName : "User Name",
 BlogId : 789
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does set the ID of the Blog in the controller, but it looks like it's just creating a blank Blog with only the ID populated and thus the POST fails the `(ModelState.IsValid)`?

Comment: thats why i was advocating for a separate view model